# How forward a message without showing sender's name in pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

```
def send_client(message):
    bot.send_message(client_id, f'<b>Someone sent you a message. This is what they said:</b>',
                 parse_mode='html')
    bot.forward_message(client, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Message is sent. Thank you for using me!</b>', parse_mode='html')
```

But it forwards a message without hiding a sender's name  [Shows my name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsXKl.png)

I wanted to make a bot that would anonymously forward a message from one person to another. But doing it with `send_message` would be a little bit problematic, if someone wants to send a photo, or music for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `copy_message()` instead of `forward_message()`. More about in the [documentation](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.copy_message).